# What is the derivative of $\int_{-10}^{-3} e^{\tan(t)} \,dt$ with respect to x?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, infinity

We were learning about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus today in my high school and the above integral came up as an example of an integral with a "constant" value. At first I accepted that the derivative of it was zero, but then I realized that since derivatives are defined for radian versions of the trigonometric functions, $e^{\tan(t)}$ does not satisfy the continuity requirement for it to be *guaranteed* to have an convergent integral on the interval $[-10, -3]$.

I had my suspicions that the integral did not exist as a real number, so I checked it with the NINT tool on my graphing calculator and got $\infty$. I also cross-validated the result with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+e%5Etan%28x%29+from+-10+to+-3) and reaffirmed that the integral does not converge to any real number.

Yet a peer pointed out that the calculator also evaluated the derivative of $\infty$ as $0$, and WolframAlpha confirms that as well.

**My Question**

Is the derivative of $\infty$ truly $0$? It seems rediculous to me to treat it as a constant since it's only a concept, but has someone defined a use or reason for it to be that way?

Comment: I read only the title. Where is $x$?

Comment: It seems your teacher or textbook gave a bad example. He/she/it probably wanted a strange-looking integral and did not bother to check that it was convergent. It is also slightly possible that the variable $t$ is meant to be in degrees rather than radians. You shouldn't worry about it much: as I teacher, I can tell you that teachers make mistakes.

Comment: @sinbadh: The point of the example is that there is no $x$ in the expression, therefore it is a constant and the derivative is zero. The teacher or book just messed up and used an undefined integral.

Comment: The derivative with respect to $x$ is 0: there's no $x$ in the expression, so it's a constant function of $x$. It's either a typo or a trick question. I see I'm not the first to observe this, @RoryDaulton .

Comment: Whilst we cannot treat $\infty$ as a standard constant, I fail to see now its derivative can be anything other than $0$ by looking at what $\frac{d}{dx}$ actually means

Answer (score 3):

Zero. The value of the integral doesn't depend on $x$ at all.

Comment: This doesn't really address my main point. I agree that under normal conditions it would be zero, but my problem is that the value of the integral itself is undefined and treating an undefined value the same as a constant felt wrong to me.

Comment: @CaptainObvious, right you are, forgot about the singularities of $\tan$.